# WPF ToolbarControl overflow amounts

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing an application that has multiple ToolbarControls. There are other UI elements between the toolbars, so I cannot use ToolbarManagers. Here is the UI Hierarchy:

```
<UserControl>
     <DockPanel>
           <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <ToolbarTray> <Toolbar/> <ToolbarTray/>
                <Some Other UI Stuff, separators, text, etc/>
           <StackPanel/>

           <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <ToolbarTray> <Toolbar/> <ToolbarTray/>
                <Some Other UI Stuff, separators, text, etc/>
           <StackPanel/>



           <!-- as the above toolbars expand in size, these two are pushed offscreen>
           <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                <Some Other UI Stuff, separators, text, etc/>
           <StackPanel/>
    <DockPanel/>
<UserControl/>
```

My question is, how can I make the `Toolbar` controls show as many buttons as possible? They overflow into a dropdown menu when full, but currently their `MaxHeight` values are all hard coded. I am looking to make this dynamic, so the maximum number of buttons appear depending on the size of the monitor. I've tried doing so by removing the height restrictions, but then the last `StackPanel` always just gets forced off screen.

Notice that the last `StackPanel` MUST reside on the bottom of the `DockPanel`, and contains no toolbar but only some other UI elements.

Comment: Does using `Grid`s with row definitions instead of the first two `StackPanel`s help? `StackPanel` always uses the all available space.

Comment: I have to use stackpanels because of the apps behavior. It rotates from vertical orientation to horizontal orientation

Comment: You can change the `RowDefinitions`s to `ColumnDefinition`s and update the `Grid.Row` or `Grid.Column` properties of children accordingly.

Comment: To accommodate for orientation? Yes, I could, but given the intended UI design of the app it's considerably easier to use stackpanels. I'm just wondering why they are allowed to be pushed completely out of the bounds of the usercontrol....

Comment: Another way is to bind the `Height` property of your `StackPanel` to some other parent control's `Height`. But, I am not sure if this is what you want. Can you include some screenshots?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up responses.. Unfortunately I'm unable to include screenshots due to employer restrictions. For further context, the application is an AppBar (SHAppBarMessage calls used) that does taskbar like docking.

Comment: Does your AppBar use a constant portion of your screen? If this is the case you can bind the `Height` property with a converter that converts your parent control's `Height` with a given ratio.

Comment: I so wish it did. It does not use a constant portion of the screen, it can be resized which is the source of this problem. :(

Comment: Can you be more specific about the "dynamic"? Do you have some algorithm in mind or should the user be able to resize the toolbar area or something completely different?

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness. The resize occurs because this app will be run on a remote desktop connection, where the user can resize the entire display size of the remote connection. However, the app itself will always fill the entire display edge.

Comment: I mean something different... you have some area for your application, no matter whether it is the screen size, the window size or something different. How do you want to distribute the given area between your UI elements? How much space at min/max/between for the toolbars, how much space for the other stackpanel?

Comment: Ahh I see. I would like the first ToolBarControl to expand to fit (minimum) half of its elements, and the second ToolBarControl to fit as much as possible thereafter.

Comment: "as much as possible" with some restriction, right? You complained about your stackpanel being pushed off screen when you take space with the toolbars.

Comment: Yes, as much as possible without forcing the next elements off of the screen. This is the problem. I'm sorry if I was unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place the area with the highest priority first in your dockpanel.

You can test this with the following very primitive setup (place in a WPF window and resize height, observe in which order the controls are expanded / shrinked):

Your current way:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Top" Fill="Green" Height="100"/>
    <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Fill="Red" Height="100"/>
    <!-- Last one fills -->
    <Rectangle Fill="Orange"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Let bottom keep its size and shrink top first

```
<DockPanel>
    <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Fill="Red" Height="100"/>
    <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Top" Fill="Green" Height="100"/>
    <!-- Last one fills -->
    <Rectangle Fill="Orange"/>
</DockPanel>
```

A typical problem with this approach is the tab-order. You can keep the screen visible tab order as follows:

```
<DockPanel KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
    <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Fill="Red" Height="100" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="3"/>
    <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Top" Fill="Green" Height="100" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"/>
    <!-- Last one fills -->
    <Rectangle Fill="Orange" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"/>
</DockPanel>
```

I use the rectangles to make different areas and the priority of their resizing visible - you can place any of your controls in place of the rectangles.

**Edit:** regarding the comment mentioning fixed size and two relative sized areas (I took the freedom to ignore the 20%, 30% and only look at the ratio), a grid might be the better choice:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="Green"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Orange"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="Red" Height="100"/>
</Grid>
```

Regarding rotation: one way would be to *swap* the row and column definitions... make sure to include all relevant properties in the swap.

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" Margin="0,0,0,40">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Green"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Orange"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Red" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"/>
</Grid>
<Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" Content="Change Rotation" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

Code behind to swap grid rows and columns:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var rd = myGrid.RowDefinitions.ToList();
    var cd = myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.ToList();
    myGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
    myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
    foreach (var item in cd)
    {
        myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = item.Width });
    }
    foreach (var item in rd)
    {
        myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = item.Height });
    }
    foreach (UIElement child in myGrid.Children)
    {
        var r = child.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
        child.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, child.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty));
        child.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, r);
    }
}
```

It would also be possible to define different data templates for original and rotated view. It all depends on the requirements and complexity of involved controls.

Another alternative idea: lets actually rotate the view including its content... that might help if the parent container is not rotated:

```
private bool isRotated = false;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!isRotated)
    {
        myGrid.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(90, myGrid.ActualWidth / 2, myGrid.ActualHeight / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        myGrid.LayoutTransform = Transform.Identity;
    }
    isRotated = !isRotated;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve my problem. In your example, the Orange rectangle is the only one that shifts in size. The problem I am facing is that *both* the orange and green block should shift in size, while the red block remains fixed. Notice I have two toolbar controls that should be overflowing, and one fixed control on the bottom (your red block)

Comment: This is the difficulty-- scaling the two stackpanels with ToolbarControls inside them together. The ratio is 30% first stackpanel, and 20% second stackpanel, although this ratio doesn't really matter to solve the problem.

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld See my edit for a ratio-based size model. There is a solution for almost any consistent and clear layout specification, while inconsistent or incomplete requirements will fail at some point - in this case the problem is your combination of fixed size and 20%+30%, which will not add up to 100% for most window sizes. So your requirements are still not precise.

Comment: Apologies. 20%+30% for the two stackpanels with toolbarcontrols, and the remainder is left to the last stackpanel to fill.

Comment: There may be blank space between the second of the two toolbarcontrols, and the final stackpanel

Comment: I have one more followup question, if you don't mind answering that as well. If the application needed to rotate 90 degrees (i.e. it could be viewed horizontally or vertically), how would you accommodate for this in the grid? Previously I was using a dockpanel and stackpanels, which you may simply bind Orientation to something in the code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you expect the rotated application to look like... You mean like replacing rows by columns with the same size ratios or having a completely different layout?

Comment: The former. The application has rotates 90 degrees. To be analogous to this example, the rectangles are now vertical, and the application resize occurs to make the app wider, instead of taller.

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld added some rotation sample to the bottom of the answer. However, for more complex layouts I'd probably go with individually designed layout containers for each rotation case.

Comment: Thanks. My actual layout is considerably complicated. Your POC example will help though. Thanks again @grek40 :)

Comment: I thought you might be interested to know, I ended up solving this by manually changing the Height / Width properties (bound them to the code, and I do a whole bunch of math in the code). Your solution is still helpful though, and I'll leave it as the marked answer.

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld I can imagine... sometimes hard math is needed, though I prefer to use one of the automatic layout variants whenever possible.

Comment: Yeah I would have preferred it too but this application has a lot of nested controls, it would be way too difficult. Thanks for the help along the way though :)